# Want to launch default Voice recorder from application to capture audio

Tags: android

How can I launch default voice recorder available in device to record voice? I want to do that using `startActivityForResult` so that captured voice data I can get back in my activity (similar to when we launch camera to capture image). I don't know the intent action to perform this.

How can I do this. Any ideas?

Comment: This may be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2564871/default-record-voice-in-android

Comment: This is not duplicate question. I want to use default Voice Recorder available in device instead of creating my own.
In the post you mentioned, application creates its own Voice Recorder.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think [RECORD_SOUND_ACTION](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Audio.Media.html#RECORD_SOUND_ACTION) is what you're looking for.

Example:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.Audio.Media.RECORD_SOUND_ACTION); 
startActivityForResult(intent, ACTIVITY_RECORD_SOUND);
```

Comment: Thanks jasper. One more request, is that possible to supply some arguments such as 10 seconds and then the recorder should record voice not more then 10 seconds.

Comment: can you please let me know why this is recording .3gp but i want to download .mp3..